# Dynamically generate html table using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 100,000 records in java-script array with following column name "EmpNo,Fname,LName,Date."
I want to display all records in a html table with each field in a text box.

Currently i create a table and append the values in a loop

```
<td><input maxlength="8" id="EmpNo' + i + '"  type="text"  /></td>
```

It takes above 5 mints to display over 24,000 records to generate the table

**What is the best way to generate html table in java-script.?**

Comment: At first: no jQuery, then [HTMLTableElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement).

Comment: Use pagination. There is not any way to make a scalable method of table generation which will deal with 100k records.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan my requirement is to display these records in a page itself without any pagination

Comment: @Vijeeshkumarvofox then your users will have to wait the 5+ minutes for the page to render. There is no alternative.

Comment: If the requirement is to display 100K records without pagination, I would push back and inform your project manager that you simply cannot have good performance with that many records and no pagination.  If they'll sign off on the performance hit, then go with it, otherwise, go with pagination....that's my advice.  From a user's perspective, if it took 5+ minutes for your page to load, I won't stick around and wait.  Most users don't wait more than ~30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you shouldn't be trying to display 100,000 elements on a single webpage. Your method for doing so is valid but Javascript was not designed to be a language that handles IO intensive tasks like manipulating and displaying thousands of elements of an array at a time. I would suggest implementing some form of paging to be able to handle the information better.
Try looping through, say the first 500 elements and displaying them and add next page/prev page buttons to generate the table for the next 500 elements. You can use jQuery's $.clear() to empty the table before filling it again.

Comment: This is what everyone commented. This is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If pagination is not something you can do, you might be able to get better performance by generating the HTML in your server-side code and then passing that down instead of passing the data and asking Javascript to generate your HTML.